# How to change the code after adding @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and I don't understand the purpose of @tf.function. In my understanding, it changes the codes into callable Tensorflow graph. I am totally lost and don't know where to start, the only thing I know about Tensorflow is that all Tensorflow codes contain two important parts:

Part 1: building the GRAPH, it represents the data flow of the computations
Part 2: running a SESSION, it executes the operations in the graph

I provide the codes and error below. How should I fix this error:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)  #tf ver: 1.15


Z = np.loadtxt("Z.txt")   #516 rows * 2000 columns
R1 = np.loadtxt("R1.txt")   #516 rows * 1000 columns
R2 = np.loadtxt("R2.txt")   #516*49
M = np.loadtxt("M.txt")     #516*4

z_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
r_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
m_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
target_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

@tf.function
def data_split(z_data, r_data, m_data, target_data):

    ff_n = m_data.shape[1] 
    port_n = target_data.shape[1] 
    [t, n] = r_data.shape  
    p = int(z_data.shape[1] / n) 
    z_data = z_data.reshape((t, p, n)).transpose((0, 2, 1))   # dim(t,n,p)

    # train sample and test sample

    test_idx = np.arange(int(t * 1), t)
    train_idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(t), test_idx)
    t_train = np.alen(train_idx)
    z_train = z_data[train_idx]
    z_test = z_data[test_idx]
    r_train = r_data[train_idx]
    r_test = r_data[test_idx]
    target_train = target_data[train_idx]
    target_test = target_data[test_idx]
    m_train = m_data[train_idx]
    m_test = m_data[test_idx]

    return z_train, r_train, m_train, target_train, z_test, r_test, m_test, target_test, ff_n, port_n, t_train, n, p

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    z_train, r_train, m_train, target_train, z_test, r_test, m_test, target_test, ff_n, port_n, t_train, n, p = sess.run(data_split, feed_dict={z_data: Z, r_data: R1, m_data: M, target_data: R2})
```

ERROR:

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    304         self._unique_fetches.append(ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_element(
--> 305             fetch, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True))
    306       except TypeError as e:

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3606     with self._lock:
-> 3607       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3608 

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3695       raise TypeError("Can not convert a %s into a %s." %
-> 3696                       (type(obj).__name__, types_str))
   3697 

TypeError: Can not convert a Function into a Tensor or Operation.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12220/200301862.py in <module>
     40 
     41 with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
---> 42     z_train, r_train, m_train, target_train, z_test, r_test, m_test, target_test, ff_n, port_n, t_train, n, p = sess.run(data_split, feed_dict={z_data: Z, r_data: R1, m_data: M, target_data: R2})
     43 

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    954     try:
    955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 956                          run_metadata_ptr)
    957       if run_metadata:
    958         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1163     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
   1164     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
-> 1165         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1166 
   1167     # Run request and get response.

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    472     """
    473     with graph.as_default():
--> 474       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    475     self._fetches = []
    476     self._targets = []

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    274         if isinstance(fetch, tensor_type):
    275           fetches, contraction_fn = fetch_fn(fetch)
--> 276           return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
    277     # Did not find anything.
    278     raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' %

D:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    307         raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r, '
    308                         'must be a string or Tensor. (%s)' %
--> 309                         (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
    310       except ValueError as e:
    311         raise ValueError('Fetch argument %r cannot be interpreted as a '

TypeError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function object at 0x0000018CC1C31048> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a Function into a Tensor or Operation.)

​```
````

Comment: Does your code already works? If it does and you are using eager execution, then decorating your function with @tf.function is pointless. I do believe this is an X Y problem. Please tell us what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I guess you have looked here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function

Comment: I have updated my question with full codes and errors for easier diagnosis. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of passing a dictionary , Could you use [migration script](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) and use the variable directly without session in 2.8 version.                                                                                          
z_train, r_train, m_train, target_train, z_test, r_test, m_test, target_test, ff_n, port_n, t_train, n, p = data_split(z_data, r_data, m_data, target_data)